# Update Default values at library level; site columns and content type are created at Content Type Hub

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, content-type-hub, default-value, custom-content-type

We have configured 2 content types in our client tenant using Content Type Hub (CTH). There is a "Control Type" choice field in both these content types, and the client is asking to set a default value for this field based on the library.

For instance, the choice field has 3 values - *‘Controlled’*, *‘Managed’* and *‘Managed with Approval’*

The default value should be *‘Controlled’* for *Controlled libraries* and *‘Managed’* for *‘Managed’ libraries*, and *‘Managed with Approval’* for *Managed with Workflow libraries*, etc.

Based on our tests, we have observed that default values set in the library level get overwritten when there is a change in this field in the Content type hub and changes are published.

Could you please share best practices in implementing it with Content Type Hub (CTH) and other pros & cons with default values at the library level for this case?

Answer (score 0):

This is to be expected, since the content types you are using are defined in the Content Type Hub. It will set the default value to whatever is defined in the hub.

I would consider leaving the default value as unselected and allowing users to choose which option when uploading a document. If the value is always the same for all files in that library, I would question the purpose of having a choice column at all. The value in that instance would already be inferred from the library where the file is stored e.g. you know all files are controlled if they're stored in the controlled libraries.